# Date ticks and rotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I am having an issue trying to get my date ticks rotated in matplotlib. A small sample program is below. If I try to rotate the ticks at the end, the ticks do not get rotated. If I try to rotate the ticks as shown under the comment 'crashes', then matplot lib crashes.

This only happens if the x-values are dates. If I replaces the variable `dates` with the variable `t` in the call to `avail_plot`, the `xticks(rotation=70)` call works just fine inside `avail_plot`.

Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

def avail_plot(ax, x, y, label, lcolor):
    ax.plot(x,y,'b')
    ax.set_ylabel(label, rotation='horizontal', color=lcolor)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

    #crashes
    #plt.xticks(rotation=70)

    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x, [1 for a in y], 'b')
    ax2.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax2.set_ylabel('testing')

f, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
t = np.arange(0.01, 5, 1)
s1 = np.exp(t)
start = dt.datetime.now()
dates=[]
for val in t:
    next_val = start + dt.timedelta(0,val)
    dates.append(next_val)
    start = next_val

avail_plot(axs[0], dates, s1, 'testing', 'green')
avail_plot(axs[1], dates, s1, 'testing2', 'red')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, bottom=0.3)
plt.yticks([0.5,],("",""))
#doesn't crash, but does not rotate the xticks
#plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Creating a plot with dates on the x-axis is such a common task - a shame there aren't more complete examples out there.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

If you prefer a non-object-oriented approach, move `plt.xticks(rotation=70)` to right *before* the two `avail_plot` calls, eg

```
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
avail_plot(axs[0], dates, s1, 'testing', 'green')
avail_plot(axs[1], dates, s1, 'testing2', 'red')
```

This sets the rotation property before setting up the labels. Since you have two axes here, `plt.xticks` gets confused after you've made the two plots. At the point when `plt.xticks` doesn't do anything, `plt.gca()` does *not* give you the axes you want to modify, and so `plt.xticks`, which acts on the current axes, is not going to work.

For an object-oriented approach not using `plt.xticks`, you can use

```
plt.setp( axs[1].xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70 )
```

*after* the two `avail_plot` calls.  This sets the rotation on the correct axes specifically.

Comment: One other handy thing: when you call `plt.setp` you can set multiple parameters by specifying them as additional keyword arguments.  the `horizontalalignment` kwarg is particularly useful when you rotate the tick labels: `plt.setp( axs[1].xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70, horizontalalignment='right' )`

Comment: I don't like this solution as it mixes the pyplot and object-oriented approaches. You can just call `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=70)` at any place.

Comment: @TedPetrou What do you mean by "mixing" here? the `plt.setp` solution is completely object oriented. If you don't like the fact that there is some `plt` in it, use  `from matplotlib.artist import setp; 
setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)` instead.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The first line of code uses `plt.xticks` which is pyplot. The documentation itself says not to mix styles. `plt.setp` is more verbose but not the typical object-oriented style either. Your answer is definitely the best here. Basically, anything with a function is not object-oriented. It doesn't matter if you import `setp` or not.

Comment: Much of the question's code uses pyplot, like `yticks`, and the code doesn't have ax defined at all outside of `avail_plot`...

Comment: @cge No. He explicitly starts the problem with the object oriented approach: `f, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)`. There are exactly two other calls to `plt` besides `plt.show` so I wouldn't say much of the code uses pyplot. The `setp` solution is actually good and explicit. `plt.xticks` is not.

Comment: this did not have any effect on the plot, but fig.autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.2, rotation=30, ha='right') helped!

Comment: When you set tick `rotation`, you probably also want to set `horizontalalignment`, e.g. `plt.xticks(rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')`

Answer (score 215):

**Solution works for matplotlib 2.1+**

There exists an axes method `tick_params` that can change tick properties. It also exists as an axis method as `set_tick_params`

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
```

Or

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=45)
```

As a side note, the current solution mixes the stateful interface (using pyplot) with the object-oriented interface by using the command `plt.xticks(rotation=70)`. Since the code in the question uses the object-oriented approach, it's best to stick to that approach throughout. The solution does give a good explicit solution with `plt.setp( axs[1].xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70 )`

Comment: Is it possible to change the default rotation for all plots? I think I need to change this on every plot I make.

Comment: Seems the most OOP method here.

Answer (score 59):

An easy solution which avoids looping over the ticklabes is to just use

[`fig.autofmt_xdate()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate)

This command automatically rotates the xaxis labels and adjusts their position. The default values are a rotation angle 30° and horizontal alignment "right". But they can be changed in the function call

```
fig.autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.2, rotation=30, ha='right')
```

The additional `bottom` argument is equivalent to setting `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=bottom)`, which allows to set the bottom axes padding to a larger value to host the rotated ticklabels.

So basically here you have all the settings you need to have a nice date axis in a single command.

A [good example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) can be found on the matplotlib page.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: can you control 'rotation_mode' parameter through this function?

Comment: @TheoryX No. If you need rotation_mode, you need to either use the `plt.setp` approach, or loop over the ticks (which is essentially the same).

Comment: Yes it is an easy solution only when the x axis present at the bottom of the graph. However, when the x axis is at the top of the graph or when two x axes (`twinx`) are present, it screwes up the alignment between ticks and tick labels. In that case, solution by Ted Petrou is better.

Comment: @Śubham Correct. This is mainly a shortcut to all the other solutions for the most common case.

Answer (score 22):

Another way to apply`horizontalalignment` and `rotation` to each tick label is doing a `for` loop over the tick labels you want to change:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
hours = [now + dt.timedelta(minutes=x) for x in range(0,24*60,10)]
days = [now + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in np.arange(0,30,1/4.)]
hours_value = np.random.random(len(hours))
days_value = np.random.random(len(days))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.75)
axs[0].plot(hours,hours_value)
axs[1].plot(days,days_value)

for label in axs[0].get_xmajorticklabels() + axs[1].get_xmajorticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(30)
    label.set_horizontalalignment("right")
```

[image]

And here is an example if you want to control the location of major and minor ticks:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.75)
now = dt.datetime.now()
hours = [now + dt.timedelta(minutes=x) for x in range(0,24*60,10)]
days = [now + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in np.arange(0,30,1/4.)]

axs[0].plot(hours,np.random.random(len(hours)))
x_major_lct = mpl.dates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=2,maxticks=10, interval_multiples=True)
x_minor_lct = matplotlib.dates.HourLocator(byhour = range(0,25,1))
x_fmt = matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter(x_major_lct)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_lct)
axs[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(x_minor_lct)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_fmt)
axs[0].set_xlabel("minor ticks set to every hour, major ticks start with 00:00")

axs[1].plot(days,np.random.random(len(days)))
x_major_lct = mpl.dates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=2,maxticks=10, interval_multiples=True)
x_minor_lct = matplotlib.dates.DayLocator(bymonthday = range(0,32,1))
x_fmt = matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter(x_major_lct)
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_lct)
axs[1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(x_minor_lct)
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_fmt)
axs[1].set_xlabel("minor ticks set to every day, major ticks show first day of month")
for label in axs[0].get_xmajorticklabels() + axs[1].get_xmajorticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(30)
    label.set_horizontalalignment("right")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me on matplotlib v1.5.1 (I'm stuck on a legacy version of matplotlib at work, don't ask why)

Comment: I just tested with python3.6 and matplotlib v2.2.2 and it works too.

Answer (score 9):

I am clearly late but there is an official example which uses

```py
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")
```

to rotate the labels while keeping them correctly aligned with the ticks, which is both clean and easy.

Ref: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Answer (score 6):

Simply use

```
ax.set_xticklabels(label_list, rotation=45)
```