# python rotate values on xaxis to not overlap

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I'm having some problems with the xticks of the graph here:
[image]

Can anyone help?

I tried what they did here: [Date ticks and rotation in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264521/date-ticks-and-rotation-in-matplotlib) but to no avail.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as DT
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

#import data
i, time, temp, hum, light_lv, light_v = np.loadtxt('DHT11.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1,
                     usecols = (0,2,3,4,5,6), unpack = 1)

#id, unixtime, temp, humidity, lightlevel, lightvolt


time = [DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in time]
light_lv =  250 - light_lv

xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

if 1:


    host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
    host.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()

    offset = 60
    new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                        axes=par2,
                                        offset=(offset, 0))

    par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)



    #host.set_xlim(0, 25)
    host.set_ylim(15, 25)

    host.set_xlabel("Time (unix)")
    host.set_ylabel("Temperature (C)")
    par1.set_ylabel("Humidity (%)")
    par2.set_ylabel("Light (A.U.)")

    p1, = host.plot(time, temp)
    p2, = par1.plot(time, hum)
    p3, = par2.plot(time, light_lv)

    #par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
    #par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

    host.legend()

    host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
    par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

    plt.draw()
    plt.show()

    #plt.savefig("Test")
```

Comment: i guess you did not notice the xtick labels in my solution to your other question

Answer (score 2):

I find the easiest way to work out things like this in matplotlib is just look through the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) until you find one that has what you want, and just copy that bit.

[Look at this one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html)

You want this:

```
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
```

There is another techniqued used [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html):

```
# Set the axes ranges and axes labels
ax1.set_xlim(0.5, numBoxes+0.5)
top = 40
bottom = -5
ax1.set_ylim(bottom, top)
xtickNames = plt.setp(ax1, xticklabels=np.repeat(randomDists, 2))
plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=45, fontsize=8)
```

alternatively, and this looks easier, you can just do what's done in this answer.

```
plt.xticks(rotation=<whatever>)
```

just put that in before you plot anything.

Comment: (basically everywhere in the `if 1:`part)

Comment: don't do `plt.xticks...` try doing them on the axes objects

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you. I added the following line and was able to rotate the custom x-axis tick labels:

```
ax1.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction("left")
```

I found that little bit of code on this page of the documentation - see the "Rotation and Alignment of TickLabels" section:
http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axisartist.html

I also stumbled across a devdocs page, that says that most of the typical tick-related mpl code doesn't really work with the mpl_toolkits.axisartist implementation.

A similar warning is at the top of the AxisGrid documentation:
http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html?highlight=host_subplot