# Xlabels not aligned to points on a matplotlib timeline

Tags: matplotlib

The closest post I found on SO is as follows ([Date ticks and rotation in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264521/date-ticks-and-rotation-in-matplotlib)), but still doesnt solve my issue. I need to align the years to appear directly below the red square boxes. I have tried autoformat and align keywords, but nothing works. Anyone can show what am I doing wrong?

```
dates = [df_filtered.release_date.min(),wm_director.release_date.min(),wd.loc[7283,'Year'],wd.loc[9125,'Year'],
     wd.loc[10127,'Year']]
texts = ['1st movie released','1st movie directed by woman','1st Best Director nomination','Best Director won',
     '2nd Best Director Nomination']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,1))
ax.plot((dates[0],dates[-1]),(0,0),'k',alpha=0.3)

for i, (text,date) in enumerate(zip(texts,dates)):
    ax.scatter(date,0,marker='s', s=100,color='crimson')
    ax.text(date,0.01,text,rotation=45,va="bottom",fontsize=14)
    ax.set_xticklabels([i.year for i in dates])

ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.grid('off')
ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

The list of dates are obtained by extracting the relevant rows from various dataframes, with values already converted to datatime format.

[image: My timeline]

Comment: Any chance this can be turned into a [mcve], such that one can actually provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you only set the `xticklabels`, but let `matplotlib` figure out the `xtick` positions itself. The default is to produce equally spaced `xticks`, which is not what you want. If you add the line `ax.set_xticks(dates)` before you set the `xticklabels`, you get what you want:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['1916', '1938', '1993', '2009', '2017']),format='%Y')
dates = [d for d in dates]

texts = ['1st movie released','1st movie directed by woman','1st Best Director nomination','Best Director won',
     '2nd Best Director Nomination']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,1))
ax.plot((dates[0],dates[-1]),(0,0),'k',alpha=0.3)

for i, (text,date) in enumerate(zip(texts,dates)):
    ax.scatter(date,0,marker='s', s=100,color='crimson')
    ax.text(date,0.01,text,rotation=45,va="bottom",fontsize=14)

ax.set_xticks(dates)
ax.set_xticklabels([i.year for i in dates])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both',length=0)

ax.set_ylim([-0.01,0.01])

ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.grid('off')
ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2,top=0.9)
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticklabels([])
plt.savefig('align_years.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The final image (after some code adjustments, and using `savefig` instead of `show`) now looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

Comment: works wonderfully, thanks! For understanding the code, I tried to remove this line ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',lenght=0) and it's still aligned to the red squares. I guess there's no need for the 3rd line.

Comment: @Zoozoo yes, you are right. The third line is only there because I was trying to reproduce your plot as closely as possible. If you leave out the third line, you get tick lines above the years, which I don't see in your example figure.